# Support different screens

Tags: android, material-design

In Support of different screens in android

In android 360dpi = 5.0

When use xml 360 dpi for screen mobile 5.0 
In  emulator is good

but  when run in device screens 5.0  Size is not suitable

Why ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to visit this **[link](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)** for a step-by-step tutorial and a better understanding about supporting multiple screen sizes in Android development